# Multiple choice question

Tags: feature-request, tags

**Should we add a [multiple-choice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice) tag?**
(Feel free to make choice A, B or C into a posted answer or,
of course, to add a choice D or other.)

**A.** None of the following.
  Sometimes known as an unadorned downvote to a Meta question.

**B.** Yes.
  [multiple-choice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice) could help focus intriguing puzzles
  that are being closed for being broadly ambiguous
  instead of having a chance to be worked or voted on.
  Puzzles such as those would still be put on hold
  but with the suggestion that they be converted to [multiple-choice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice),
  with examples being a mere tag-click away.
  The description for [multiple-choice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice) could be something like:

> A multiple-choice question presents a limited list
>   of specific options from which to select an answer.
>   Correct answers are evaluated based on the reasoning that supports them.

**C.** Yes, and abandon [iq-test](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iq-test).
  Almost all objective IQ test problems are multiple choice.
  A large portion of multiple-choice questions *could* appear on an IQ test.
  Whether or not a puzzle stems from an actual IQ test
  is basically a curiosity that can just as well be searched for.

Most of the 17 currently-open [iq-test](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iq-test) puzzles
  might as well be retagged as [multiple-choice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice).
  The
  [1,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/how-to-approach-pattern-finding-questions)
  [2,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17122/how-can-the-animals-get-across-the-river-without-a-fight-breaking-out)
  [3,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35019/solve-to-find-the-numerical-value-of-the-shapes)
  [4,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20111/set-the-aliens-straight)
  [5,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20126/frustrate-the-aliens-further)
   [6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20631/aliens-are-continuing-to-probe-the-human-psyche)
  that are not multiple choice include other tags as well,
  and their connections to actual IQ test questions seem fairly weak anyhow,
  especially in their posted forms.

The present description for [iq-test](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iq-test), below,
  effectively differs from the
  suggested [multiple-choice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-choice) description, above,
  in mentioning *intelligence* — a
  concept so vague that it applies not only to virtually all puzzles
  but also, as is by now widely recognized in psychology,
  only in an essentially colloquial and often misused sense.

> IQ tests are commonly used to estimate the intelligence of a person.
>   Often, you're given a set of elements with a common (but unknown) property
>   and you have to deduce the next or a missing element in the series.
>   Usually, you have to choose the solution between few options.

(Incidentally, the present [tribond](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tribond) tag could be modified to
   something like [commonality](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commonality) to include the
   “common (but unknown) property”
   aspect of this [iq-test](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iq-test) description.
   But that's another kettle of fish.)